# Not able to copy headerfile in xyz.h

Tags: file, openssl, header-files

I generated DH parameter with the following.

```
openssl dhparam -C -5 1024 > xyz.h
```

I tried to generate DH paramter header file and copied into xyz.h in windows openssl.exe but not able to copy headerfile in xyz.h

Comment: Please state the compiler and OpenSSL version. Please provide the source of the error and the exact error message for ***`... not able to copy headerfile in xyz.h`***. Also see [Weak Diffie-Hellman and the Logjam Attack](https://weakdh.org/)

Comment: @jww : i tried with openssl 1.0.2h.  header file is displayed on consol but not able to copy into another text file. it doesn't give any error.